# Python and GCP getIamPolicy for a project

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to get a list of users and their access for a project.

Http doesn't work as we're behind a firewall and I just get a response `not ready error`.

I have some code ...

```
import google.cloud.resource_manager

keyfile="xxxxx.json"
client = google.cloud.resource_manager.client.Client.from_service_account_json(keyfile)

for project in client.list_projects():
    print("%s, %s" % (project.project_id, project.status))    # Works Fine
    print project.getIamPolicy()
```

The first print statement works but I can't find the correct syntax for `getIamPolicy` although it does seem to be possible according to documentation.

If any one else have done this, can you supply me with the full syntax?

I wish to do this from within a python script, not using the command line or sub processes.

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

Install the client library.

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth google-auth-httplib2
```

And use the following code to list all the users and their role on the project, just update `PROJECT_ID` with the project ID you want to check and `xxxxxx.json` with your credentials.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename='xxxxxx.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

response = service.projects().getIamPolicy(resource=PROJECT_ID, body={}).execute()
print response
```

For more references you can the check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy).